# How to get rid of voltage spikes in this supply voltage switcher circuit?

Tags: analog, power-electronics, protection

In my mainboard there are two main supply.
One is 12V and other one is 5V.

5V is always ON but there is a risk of 12V crashing and disappearing. So, I want something like this, when presence of 12V main supply always has to be 12V but when it is gone main supply must be 5V which is always ON. The crudial thing here is main supply must never be below 4.8V.

I used to get this done by this simple structure:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEjYK1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But my client does not want that. Diodes get hot and there is a certain voltage drop. So I thought of this soltion:

[image]

It is doing its job but it can not prevent this annoying spikes:
 [image]

You see, when both rising and falling of 12V, it leads a spike and it causes to voltage drop below 5V. I want to understand why does it happen? And is there any circuit that can do the job with high efficiency?

Comment: Have you tried Schottky diodes?

Comment: If Olins Scottkys aren't cold enough for you, there are purpose made MOSFET based power ORing ICs. How much current are you passing?

Comment: I don't understand why you put the complex MOSFET switching on the 12V input, and still just a diode at the 5V input. The diode voltage drop is much more of a problem on the 5V input, since your lower limit is 4.8V. Also, you must state your current requirements.

Comment: @winny Thanks for the answers. I was using schottky diodes. When 12V ON it supplies digital functions and much more powerful circuits so it draws a lot of current! But when 12V fails, 5V only supplies for standby operatings and basic functions (supplied by 5V) and draws only 150 - 200 mA.

Comment: "a lot" is dubious. Give numbers.

Comment: 1st define Vin vs I load R  plus reactance. X(f) and uF

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: in ltspice ground can't rise

Comment: yes how silly of me. Of course it is  the FET Miller Gate Drain capacitance loading the 5V supply from gate drive using 2N3055 too fast. reducing gate current and slew rate with a choke on drain such that dv/dt= I/C is less than 50mV

Comment: it looks like M1 is turning on while  "V1" is less than 5V

Comment: @Jasen Definitely the case - Q1 is a crazy large power NPN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output voltage is dipping because the power PFET is shorting the output node to the 12V supply that is at a lower voltage. Your threshold for turning on the PFET is much lower than 5V, effectively less than 1V.

I went ahead and remade your schematic in LTSpice:

[image: Really, I'm just doing this to have pretty waveforms]

The first question you should ask is *"When does the NPN turn on?"*, which is practically immediately. There's a couple reasons for this:

1. Your NPN, a 2N3055, is a big, power NPN (15 A!!). You need maybe 1-3mA at most to turn on the PFET with the R3-R4 resistor divider.
2. Because Q1 is so large, it really doesn't take much to turn it on a little bit. LTSpice has that transistor turning on at about 0.27V, which is probably less than you assumed.
3. I think you have your R1 and R2 values backwards. Even assuming a target VBE of 0.6V, your NPN would be on when the 12V rail was at 0.73V. The other way around, and it turns on at 3.43V or so (but probably lower).

Taking those things into account, we can see the voltages of the 12V rail (red), the NPN VBE (green), and the MOSFET gate voltage (blue). We can see the MOSFET turns on almost instantly.

[image]

For more fun, here's a look at the DC sweep of V2 (the 12V supply) when V1 (the 5V supply) is held at 5.0V:

[image]

The current through D1 and M1 spikes to 27A, but really that's just what the diode model is limiting it to - the diode would probably blow up if the 12V supply was *really* an ideal source. The diode is only rated for about 1A.

I'll admit, I'm not very fond of this topology, and I would probably look for a power management IC, or maybe some "ideal" diode ICs to handle the switching in a controlled manner. A comparator would be another solution. Keeping the 5V rail from back-feeding the 12V rail will be a bit tricky.

To tweak this topology, swap the 2N3055 for a 2N3904. Adjust the R1/R2 ratio to turn on Q1 when the 12V rail is above 5V. I'm pretty sure you don't need R4. The problem you will run into is that the behavior will be fairly sensitive to device variation (bad for products).

Comment: turns on at below 0.3V... wow!

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic is hard to see, and so is your graph.  From the description, it seems the problem is that the output is glitching off during the switching between 12 V and 5 V input.

If so, use what you had before *in addition* to your active circuit.  However, use Schottky diodes for lower voltage drop.  The diodes will guarantee the output is help up to the minimum of the two inputs, minus the diode drop.  This is regardless of what your active switch is doing.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2wzBf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is the threshold for NPN switch to Gate is too low and it turned on a 4V  pulling down 5V

there are better ways to to do this. but I am just showing a rough example to make it work using your design.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tony, I just don't think the CRSS is a factor in this simulation, primarily because everything is happening so slowly. In fact, a DC sweep (no capacitance) shows the MOSFET turning on when the 12V rail is only 0.3V

Comment: @W5VO  You are totally correct. His NPN bias should not turn on until 12V exceeds 5V .  This is why it drops below 4V when NPN turns on 12V when it is 4V  and pulls down.  As you said his R values are reversed and should be biased more like to turn on at 10V.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar problem. I needed to keep an MCU and display running from either USB or 12V, whichever was available, to supply about 100 mA. I found a simple and robust solution.

Instead of focusing on the narrow problem definition, it helped to look at it from bigger perspective. In other words, instead of thinking "I need to switch between 12V and 5V supplies", the bigger issue was "I need to provide constant 5V to this circuit".

My solution is below.

I used an LDO from 5V USB and set to 5V output. The LDO can supply 200 mA with only a 100 mV drop between In and Out.

On 12V side, I used an old LM317 to put out 5.1 Volts since 0.7 Watt of heat was OK and I wanted very good input overvoltage protection. You can use an SMPS for yours if you need low Pdiss.

The 5V LDO gets overridden by the slightly higher 5.1 Volts from 12V and the LDO just shuts off.

Lots of advantages to using regulators instead of Schottky diodes or MOSFETs:

1. Overload protection
2. Short circuit protection
3. Thermal protection
4. Very fast switching between supplies with little to no dip during switching

I hope this helps. -Vince

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE2DJL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>